# jQuery getting height of div returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a jquery html object:

```
var $header = $('<div id="print-header" class="print-header" style="width: ' + this.previewWidth + 'px; min-height: 190px;"></div>');
```

When I output it with `console.log($header);` I can see the object.

Now after that comes a for loop that appends elements, with a `float: left` on them to the `$header` object

```
for(var i = 0; i < $form.length; i++){
  var $widget = $form[i];

  var wHtml = '<div class="element" style="width: ' + $widget.size_x*10 + '%; height: ' + $widget.size_y*10 + '%; float: left;">';
  switch($widget.widget_name){
    case "textFieldWidget":
      wHtml += '<div style="border-bottom: 2px dotted; width: 100%; height: 30px; margin: 5px;"><span style="position: relative; font-size: 11px; font-style: italic; color: #999; top: 16; left: 10;">' + $widget.name + '</span></div>';
    break;
    ...
    case "imageWidget":
      wHtml += '<div style="margin: 5px;"><img src="' + $widget.options[0].value + '" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>';
    break;
  }
  wHtml += '</div>';

  if($widget.section == 0){
    $header.append(wHtml);
  }
  ...
}
```

During the loop, when the element has been appended, I append a clearfix to the `$header`

```
$header.append('<div class="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>');
```

At this point I need to calculate the `$header` height to do some further processing and this is the part where I'm stuck. No matter whether I use `.height()`, `.outerHeight()`, `.innerHeight()` or `.prop("scrollHeight")`, the height is always returned 0.

```
console.log($header); // returns the $header object
console.log("Normal: " + $header.height()); // returns 0
console.log("Outer: " + $header.outerHeight()); // returns 0
console.log("Inner: " + $header.innerHeight()); // returns 0
console.log("Scroll: " + $header.prop("scrollHeight")); // returns 0
```

I have tried using `$(window).load()`, that didn't work. The div is visible (`display: block;`). I also tried adding `overflow: hidden;`, that didn't work aswell

Comment: Could you please your queries are make it in a fiddle?

Comment: Interpreting @sudharsan 's Message : Could you please demonstrate your queries through a Fiddle..?

Comment: Have you tried to put class 'clear' to your 'print-header'? Or simple put float:left also for if. But without your code we can predict the behavior.

Comment: But $header isn't appended to the DOM, looks like...

Answer (score 0):

After appending elements to DOM the Browser needs to render. With a short wait you should be able to get the height.

First make sure you append the header to the DOM otherwise it's not rendered and hence never gets a height.

```
document.body.appendChild($header);

$header.append('<div class="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>');
console.log($header); // returns the $header object

setTimeout(function(){

     console.log("Normal: " + $header.height()); 
     console.log("Outer: " + $header.outerHeight());
     console.log("Inner: " + $header.innerHeight());
     console.log("Scroll: " + $header.prop("scrollHeight"));
}, 100);
```

Comment: append() works synchronously, a timeout seems useless here, maybe could be usefull on IE8< where engine s*cks (delay on redrw/reflow) but not on all modern browsers

Comment: `First make sure you append the header to the DOM otherwise it's not rendered` I guess this is OP's issue :)

Comment: then we don't need any `setTimeout` to delay it, get it right after it's appended.

Comment: append() works synchronously, but the rendering doesn't. Only after rendering you get a height(depending on css etc.)

Comment: @edispring You could test it on all modern browsers, the style is computed as soon as element is appended to the DOM. AFAIK, only old IE version get issue regarding this

Comment: @edispring I've tested it and it works OK without any delaying. BTW, your `document` does not have any `append` method if you mean it as the pure JS object `window.document`.

Comment: @KingKing, thanks I changed it to `document.body.appendChild`, some devs can't handle code samples which are not _production-ready_ ;-) I used the timeout mainly because of textarea elements which seem to take longer to get their height...